# No native mode forcing panel scaling

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have Dual OS in my computer, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10.

Until recently, both OS were working fine, but recently, when I get the GRUB menu and choose Ubuntu, I get the following error message

```
12.303490 0xD591: i2c wr fail : -6
12.486001 no native mode , forcing panel scaling
```

I probably think some virus on windows might have affected the ubuntu partition 
Anyway, Please kindly help me to get back my Ubuntu.

Comment: @SimplySimon , do you know the answer or do u any temporary solution , I am a nwebie to Ubuntu / linux

Comment: I don't think that it is a virus, unless you know that a virus has damaged the Hard Disk. I'll have a look around for you and see if I can find anything

Answer (score 0):

OK I have had a look around the Internet and found a few references to this problem. Apparently it is the **Nvidia Graphics Drivers** causing the problem... *now you're going to tell me that you do not have **Nvidia Graphics Card**, if you do not, let me know else, continue reading.*

The way to get around this can be approached from two different ways. The first way assumes that you can NOT start Ubuntu.

**From GRUB**

1. When the GRUB menu shows, press the <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

   If the GRUB menu isn't showing, press on the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, imediatly after the BIOS screen, to display it.
2. Select Advanced options
   Navigate through this until you can start Ubuntu. *(I only have Ubuntu on my computer, so can not remember what the exact menus there are to choose from)* If you get stuck here,

   If you can not get to, or past these options, you may need to download and run [Boot Repair](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10871917#post10871917)

**Once Ubuntu has started**

1. Click on the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch Terminal.
2. Type the following command in to the Terminal window.

   ```
   software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4
   ```

   This will open a window (after a delay) which looks like this: [image]
3. From the list of available drivers, *(None displayed on this system as I do not have a Nvidia Graphics Card!)* select one of the Proprietary Drivers from the list. If this doesn't work, try each one in turn, until you find one that works.

Comment: Hey , thanks a lot , When I go to adv. option >> recovery mode ,  I get A window where there are a lot of options like Resume normal boot , dpkg for repairing broken packages , but when i click on that , I get a dialogue box where It says mount on filesysystem some blah blah , is it ok if i say yes and continue